# how to track vehicle from php side

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm working on a php and android base project. From php side we will be giving a route to follow to android side with google map link(to make it easy)
when the android user start driving the car we have to track whether he is following the route that we gave how to do it from php side this route is given by providing a link to google map marked with the route.
              Now to track vehicle i'm confused how to start any help will be good

Comment: To make this a Stack Overflow question you're going to have to show **what you've tried**.

Comment: i have said what is my present position is i can't post my complete codes because of company's policy

Comment: This is a general advice question that’s better suited to discussion forums like [Quora](http://quora.com), or Reddit’s [`/r/programming`](http://reddit.com/r/programming/). Stack Overflow is specifically about programming-related questions as they pertain to actual code. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com).

Answer (score 1):

It's easy...

The android app have to send the GPS coordinates (with precision) with a http-request to the php-script periodically.

After that the PHP script checks the GPS coordinates + the precision and see if it's still on the marked road (this might be tricky)

Try to split up the tasks in as small pieces as possible (and use classes/functions!)

Good Luck!

Comment: ya i will try like what you said

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about google direction api. It have an `direction service` which can help you show directions on map.And for tracking location status in php application your android app need to be send device co-ordinates to your php server/application contentiously.

For getting co-ordinates you can use device GPS and android `Location Manager` Class and `Location Service`,You can also try googles geo-location api.

But remember it is must that your android app send his co-ordinates to php application according that you can show pointer for device location.